# Custom DateComboBox in Flexicious

Tags: flash, combobox, mxml

I'd like to have the drop down list of a specific DateComboBox in my Flash Builder 4.5 program to have specific font and background color of my choosing.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

DateComboBox is an extended ComboBox. You can define a style for it just like you would for a regular combobox.

```
@namespace controls "com.flexicious.controls.*";
controls|DateComboBox{
    alternating-item-colors:#FFFFFF,#FFFFFF;
    item-selection-color:#D3DFEA;
    item-roll-over-color:#DFE5EB;
    font-family:"tahoma";
    font-size:12;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-alpha:0;
    drop-shadow-visible:false;
    drop-shadow-enabled:false;
    color:#000000;
    textInputStyleName:"blackText"

}

.blackText{
    color:#000000;

}
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  I'm also having an issue when hovering over a MultiSelectComboBox, the text disappears (I assume it turns the same color as the background).  This also happens with the small arrow in both the DateComboBox and MultiSelectComboBox.  Is there a reference somewhere that lists all the style options for each type of component?  Thanks again.